# How to give layouts folder name to support multiple screen size in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to give layouts folder name to support multiple screen size in android

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific
>   resources are `small`, `normal`, `large`, and `xlarge`. For example, layouts
>   for an extra large screen should go in `layout-xlarge/`.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are
>   deprecated and you should instead use `the sw<N>dp` configuration
>   qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your
>   layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout
>   requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in
>   `layout-sw600dp/`.

Comment: can we use combination of both layout-sw600dp and layout-xlarge for multiple android version?

Comment: @SathishBabu, yes you can. From the intro blog post:<br/><br/>Previous versions of the platform will ignore any resources using the new resource qualifiers. This, then, is one approach that will work:

res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml    # For pre-3.2 tablets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 3.2 and up tablets

Comment: @Graham Borland How to get the 600dp ?

Answer (score 2):

```
res/layout– The default image folder
res/layout-sw200dp
res/layout-sw600dp
res/layout-sw800dp
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer instead of just listing some drawable folders. Also note the question was about layouts, not drawables.